# customise in-text citation of bib latex numeric style

Tags: biblatex

I am using the biblatex in my document as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

I need to produce the in-text citation to appear:

```
some text [S1] [S2]
```

and the references list to be:

```
[S1] reference details as usual
[S2] reference 2...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by using `\DeclareRefcontext{my}{labelprefix=S}` to define the prefix you want to use and adding `\newrefcontext{my}` before `\printbibliography`

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareRefcontext{my}{labelprefix=S}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}

\newrefcontext{my}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]